# react-native: ANDROID_HOME variable is not set on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: react-native, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to build my react-native project on Mac OS Big Sur. Having several issues, I ran react_native doctor command to verify my environment. Here is diagnostics report:

```
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 29.0.3
 ✖ ANDROID_HOME
```

Following multiple posts on blogs and answers on SO, I created/edited:

- .bash_profile file in my Home directory
- .bashrc file in my Home directory
- edited /etc/profile file
  ...and added following lines to these files:

  export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/piotrzielinski/Library/Android/sdk
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

Path typed in ANDROID_HOME is taken from Android Studio SDK manager.
Unfortunately, nothing worked permanently. WHat's worse, I'm not talking only about restarts - it seems that restarting VS Code (or its terminal) resets PATH variables and ANDROID_HOME is no longer available.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I failed to notice that I'm using zsh terminal (visible in title bar of SYSTEM terminal window - didn't notice it because I was using Visual Studio Code terminal!).
So, I created two files in my Home: ~/.zprofile and ~/.zshrc with contents provided in a question.
It worked. Thought it may be worthy for someone struggling the same lack of Mac OS knowledge as I do.